# How emulate a templatised std::function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, publish-subscribe, std-function

Following is a basic instance of what I am doing in my `C++` program. I have a list of listeners which are all `std::function`s. I have a concept `DataType` which means what kind of data the listener is interested in. The idea here is the same as publish-subscribe pattern. A method interested in certain kind of data should be able to add itself to the list of listeners using `AddListener`. Some methods are added & they receive a callback whenever required.

**The program works fine !!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

enum class DataType {
  Type_1,
  Type_2
  // and so on
};

typedef std::function<void(std::pair<DataType, std::string>)>   MyListenerType;

//template <typename T>
//typedef std::function<void(T>)>   MyListenerType;
// How can I emulate the above so that a method passing any kind of primitive data-type namely "int, bool, float or double" can be added into
// my vector of listners.


std::vector<MyListenerType>      my_data_listeners_1;
std::vector<MyListenerType>      my_data_listeners_2;

void ListenerMethod_Instance_1(std::pair<DataType, std::string> information) {

  DataType data_type = information.first;
  std::string message = information.second;
  std::cout << "ListenerMethod_Instance_1 called with message " << message << "\n";
}

void ListenerMethod_Instance_2(std::pair<DataType, std::string> information) {

  DataType data_type = information.first;
  std::string message = information.second;
  std::cout << "ListenerMethod_Instance_2 called with message " << message << "\n";
}

void AddListener (MyListenerType listener, DataType type_of_interest) {

  if (DataType::Type_1 == type_of_interest) {
    my_data_listeners_1.push_back(listener);
    std::cout << "Added a method instance for DataType::Type_1" << "\n";
  }
  else if (DataType::Type_2 == type_of_interest) {
    my_data_listeners_2.push_back(listener);
    std::cout << "Added a method instance for DataType::Type_2" << "\n";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Listener type not supported" << "\n";
  }
}

void CallAllListnersWhohaveSuscribed() {

  if (!my_data_listeners_1.empty()) {
    std::string send_message_1 = "some message 123";
    std::pair <DataType, std::string> info_to_send_1 = std::make_pair (DataType::Type_1, send_message_1);
    for(auto const  &listener : my_data_listeners_1) {
      listener(info_to_send_1);
    }
  }

  if (!my_data_listeners_2.empty()) {
    std::string send_message_2 = "some message 456";
    std::pair <DataType, std::string> info_to_send_2 = std::make_pair (DataType::Type_2, send_message_2);
    for(auto const  &listener : my_data_listeners_2) {
      listener(info_to_send_2);
    }
  }
}

int main() {

  // Add ListenerMethod_Instance_1 for instance
  DataType data_type_1 = DataType::Type_1;
  auto listener_instance_1 = std::bind(ListenerMethod_Instance_1, std::placeholders::_1);
  AddListener(listener_instance_1, data_type_1);

  // Add ListenerMethod_Instance_2 for instance
  DataType data_type_2 = DataType::Type_2;
  auto listener_instance_2 = std::bind(ListenerMethod_Instance_2, std::placeholders::_1);
  AddListener(listener_instance_2, data_type_2);

  CallAllListnersWhohaveSuscribed();
  return 0;
}
```

**Following is the output of the program:**

```
./stdFunctionTest
Added a method instance for DataType::Type_1
Added a method instance for DataType::Type_2
ListenerMethod_Instance_1 called with message some message 123
ListenerMethod_Instance_2 called with message some message 456
```

**But here is how I want to modify & struggling with.** *The caveat is that every `ListenerMethod_Instance_1` & `ListenerMethod_Instance_2` have to parse the pair to get their info which I don't want to. I want to enable a method of any C++ primitive data type be it "int, bool, float or double" to be able to be added into the listeners vector & receive the callback*. For example following method should be "add-able" into `AddListener`.

```
void ListenerMethod_Instance_3(int integer_data) {

  std::cout << "ListenerMethod_Instance_3 called with integer_data " << integer_data << "\n";
}
```

Looking at this [link here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm) looks somewhat possible someway. But I'm struggling to adapt it to my use-case here. Please suggest.

**So, basically how can I achieve templates functionality with `std::function`s ?**

Comment: This might be a good use for `boost::any`.

Comment: cannot use an option from boost. is there anything available in `std::` scope to leverage from ?

Comment: @HAL9000-Kernel Starting with C++17 you can use `std::any`.

Comment: To emulate `boost::any`, use a type identifier (an int) and a union of the types you want to represent. A getter template function takes a type or identifier and returns the proper union member.

Comment: Dont understand why the question is down-voted !!! Put up working & compiling code. Explained the question such elaborately. still down-voted !! anyways, let me take a look at `std::any`. But I will have to wait for `C++ 17` then ? any other possible ways to get this working under `C++ 14` ?

Comment: @HAL9000-Kernel Yes, if you don't want to require compiling in C++17 mode (I think GCC and Clang already have `std::any`, not sure about MSVC) - then `boost::any` was already mentioned, is what `std::any` was based on, and has been available for several C++ versions now. If you don't want to use Boost for whatever reason, there's probably some other similar library you can try. Oh, also, there's `::variant` in both namespaces, which can hold any type _from a predefined set_, unlike the real _any_ of `any`.

Comment: You might be able to use std::tuple with a distinct set of types that you are interested in. Thats in C++11 onward

Comment: @Caribou That just worsens the problem as far as I can tell, since (just like a basic `struct`) it lets you store multiple different data types, which are probably redundant in this case, and require the user to manually track which is active. Why not just use a basic `union` in that case? It's still bad, but not as bad as wasting the space of the inactive members.

Comment: looks like `std::any` is available as a part of `std::experimental`. looks promising

Comment: @underscore_d you are possibly right, but it might make for more general function signatures and is more "C++" than the union IMHO

Comment: @Caribou It's also much more wasteful, if I read the question correctly, and less extensible. Really being "more C++" would be achieved by using purpose-built existing or imminent library containers such as the ones already mentioned, rather than trying to shoehorn `std::tuple` into this role somehow, just so you can say you avoided `union`. Being "more C++" isn't just as simple as being "less C". :P

Comment: @KhouriGiordano What you described is an approximation of `std::variant`, not `std::any`. The point of `std::any` is that it can store _any_ type. A `union` can't because you must declare in advance the set of possible types. That's what `std::variant` does. And in both cases, we get a pile of type-checking and safely-casting methods into the bargain, none of which `union` provides.

Comment: @underscore_d I like the way you edit your comments - lol - you explain it well now.

Comment: @underscore_d Ok both `any` and `variant` are tricky to implement correctly with type safety which is why they are library features.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct anything_view_t {
  void* ptr=0;
  template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<anything_view_t, std::decay_t<T>>{}, int> =0>
  anything_view_t(T&&t):ptr(std::addressof(t)){}
  anything_view_t()=default;
  anything_view_t(anything_view_t const&)=default;
  anything_view_t& operator=(anything_view_t const&)=default;
  template<class T>
  operator T() const { return *static_cast<T*>(ptr); }
};
```

this is a very unsafe type erasing view of anything.

```
struct any_callbacks {
  std::unordered_map<std::type_index, std::vector<std::function<void(anything_view_t)>>> table;
  template<class T>
  void add_callback( std::function<void(T)> f ){
    table[typeid(T)].push_back(f);
  }
  template<class T>
  void invoke_callbacks(T t) const {
    auto it = table.find(typeid(T));
    if (it==table.end()) return;
    for(auto&&f:it->second)
      f(t);
  }
};
```

something like the above should work.  The type `T` must match exactly.  References not supported.  Code not compiled, design is sound, probably has typos.

This is not restructed to primitive types.  You should pass `T` explicitly, don't rely on deduction as that is fragile.